# Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8_11g.dll'

Tags: php, laravel-5, oracle11g

Please help me to connect the oracle database 11g through Laravel 5.7

I spend 4 days still don't make it out just drive me crazy

My config:

```
Win7-Sp1-64Bit,Xampp-v3.2.2,PHP-7.2.1,Laravel-5.7.1
```

I placed the file

```
 OCI8-php_oci8-2.1.8-7.2-ts-vc15-x64 (oci8.dll,oci8_11r.dll, oci8_12g.dll)
```

in xampp/php/ext

**I've created Environment Variables in User variables & System variables**:

PATH: `C:\instantclient_18_3 or C:\instantclient_12_2`

TNS_ADMIN: `C:\instantclient_18_3 or C:\instantclient_12_2`

。Also tried to install：

```
32bit-instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip

32bit-instantclient-basic-nt-12.1.0.2.0.zip

64bit-instantclient-basic-windows.x64-18.3.0.0.0dbru.zip

64bit-instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip
```

OCI8 still can't be loaded in http://localhost/index.php

and I run the command php -m still come out the same result:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'php_oci8_11g.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll (%1 is
>   not a valid Win32 application.),
>   C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_oci8_11g.dll.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'php_oci8_12c.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (%1 is
>   not a valid Win32 application.),
>   C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_oci8_12c.dll.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an article which is close to my config

https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database

Doing all the things on this article then

Add oci.dll, oraociei12.dll, and oraons.dll to apache/bin folder. Replace the existing one

Restart the Apache..

Things are being done!